# Почему std::swap определен в нескольких файлах?

Tags: c++

Почему алгоритм `std::swap()` определен в 2 заголовочных файлах: `<algorithm>` и `<utility>`?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: там же написано до   C++11  <utility>, а начиная от   C++11  <algorithm>,

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так а почему поменяли?

Comment: а кто сказл что поменяли? Просто ввели реализации  другие и другие специализированные алгоритмы для  обмена местами разных контейнерных обьектов, плюс  ввели  swap_ranges, а то что было  в <utility> никто не убирал

Answer (score -2):

там же написано до C++11 , а начиная от C++11 ,. Просто ввели реализации другие и другие специализированные алгоритмы для обмена местами разных контейнерных обьектов, плюс ввели swap_ranges, а то что было в  никто не убирал

Comment: Инетересно... Копирование чужых комментариев в ответ... Хм...